Cadence VCVS Output Limits
I am testing a vcvs and trying to use it as an ideal OP.
This is what I observed when I tried to set a "maximum output voltage" to the vcvs.
This is the simple vcvs schematic. VIP: AC=0.5,   VIN: AC=0.5, Phase=180.

This is the AC simulation result.
The one without a "maximum output voltage" shows a 1KV magnitude, which is expected as (VIP-VIN)*egain = 1000.
The one with a "maximum output voltage" shows a 0 magnitude. Shouldn't it show 1.8V instead?  1.8V is set as the "maximum output voltage".

